# Camera release Invalid Op on Moverio

Tags: android

I'm getting an Error on the Moverio Glasses bt200 while releasing Camera. On Nexus 10 everything works fine. The part, where I'm getting the Error looks like this:

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(null);
    mPreview.getHolder().removeCallback(mPreview);
    releaseCamera();
}

private void releaseCamera() {
    if(mCamera != null) {
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null;
    }
}
```

The Error-Message is:

```
hardware/ti/omap4xxx/camera/BaseCameraAdapter.cpp:1794 setState - Adapter state switch INTIALIZED_STATE Invalid Op! event = CAMERA_STOP_IMAGE_CAPTURE
```

Does anybody have any Idea, why I'm getting this Error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

change onPause() to...

```
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseCamera(); 
}
```